# Is it possible to upload images from the path mentioned in JSON data file in Postman app

Tags: postman, image-uploading, postman-collection-runner

I have a collection of requests out of which some of those require an image to be uploaded for further processing.When I manually run the collection , I select a file in the postman app and send the request.

[image: Postman app - Click on Select file option to choose a file]

But my purpose here is to run the collection using Runner in Postman app. So I tried mentioning the path in JSON Data file as mentioned below but it is not picked up by the request.

> [
>
> {
>     "video": "C:\Everyone\Postman\videos\abc.mp4"
>   }
>
> ]

[image: using video as variable mentioned in above JSON data file]